# parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘else’ (T_ELSE)

Tags: php, error

I am getting a strange error after upgrading my Magento webserver. After clicking `Add to Cart` I get the Error

```
parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘else’ (T_ELSE)
```

I have upgraded to PHP 5.6.20 from 5.4 and I am using the default `php.ini`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's the `short_open_tag` in php.ini.

As explained by [Fabrice Bourgeon](http://www.fabricebourgeon.fr/blog/magento/magento-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-else-t_else/) (in french) you would have to set `short_open_tag=On` because Magento's phtml templates use `<?` instead of `<?php`.

Comment: Which Magento phtml templates use short open tags?

Comment: @mam08ixo Honestly, I don't know. I am no Magento developer and I took the information from the source because it solved my problem and wanted it to share. After checking the code it seems to me the problem is a block comment which does not work as expected. Maybe I will delete this Q&A again.